# Has Brian Jacques's estate licensed the Redwall IP for an official role-playing game?

Tags: campaign-settings, books

Pretty much what it says on the tin. Is there an RPG system that has been licensed for the Redwall setting created by Brian Jacques? I expect the answer to be "No" so as a follow up, has there been any material created to re-skin an existing system to take place in that setting?

Comment: Considering the answer you have accepted, I don’t think the edit here was fair—the answer you have accepted is a poor one to the question you have changed this too. I think this should be reverted and re-closed. The question as-is *might* be acceptable, but not if it’s a none-too-subtle dodge around the ban on game-rec questions.

Comment: @KRyan I was wary of the question even when suggesting the edit that was eventually made to the title and still concerned when the question's body was so lightly edited. Yet the title specifies licensing, so I figured it was acceptable as, essentially, a `games-industry` question like *Who owns the license to produce an RPG based on this IP?* While not a *great* question as such information is usually pretty readily available, an answer may still require some digging (cf. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistborn#Role-playing_game)) and expertise in evaluating results, if any.

Comment: @KRyan (Not that I want to see the site deluged by questions of who holds what license for every obscure IP—such questions are better-suited to an author's forums or by contacting the author or her representatives directly—, but the Redwall IP is a big enough deal that I figured it'd be okay; we're not talking, like, [Thursday Next](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thursday_Next) here or anything, even though I wish we were.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You want Mouse Guard.

There's no licensed game for *Redwall*, but [the Mouse Guard RPG](http://www.mouseguard.net/book/role-playing-game/) is the closest you'll get. Based on the comic book by David Petersen, in the world of Mouse Guard, "mice struggle to live safely and prosper amongst harsh conditions and a host of predators" — which it has in common with Redwall. David Petersen himself commented upon *Redwall* with respect to *Mouse Guard* in [his blog post memorializing Brian Jacques](https://davidpetersen.blogspot.com/2011/02/rest-in-peace-mr.html):

> *Redwall* was as much an influence on *Mouse Guard* as it was an anti-influence. It was while I was developing the ideas for my own group of mouse rangers I was handed the first book in the series. I thoroughly enjoyed Brian's writing, and his gift for including vocal accents into the text. It charged in me even more desire to pursue my love of animal stories and medieval cultures.
>
> However, I knew instantly that I could never top what Mr. Jacques was doing. So when I say his books were a counter influence, I only mean that I had to set out in a different path from what he was already master of.

The Mouse Guard RPG deals with fantasy rodent and smallfolk culture, handles combat well, and is a beautiful game besides.